# Scattering cross section temperature dependence

Tags: cosmology, temperature, nuclear-physics, scattering-cross-section

In the book of [Barbara Ryden, Introduction to Cosmology](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/introduction-to-cosmology/7E9E7C9C717570F1FFB3BA70F864A8FA#overview), the author states that $\sigma$ proportional to $T^2 $:

> Neutrinos interact with baryons via the weak nuclear force. At the temperatures we are considering, the cross-sections for weak interactions are small. At temperatures $kT \approx 1~\textrm{MeV}$, the cross-section for the interaction of a neutrino with a proton or neutron is:
>
> $$ \sigma_w \approx 10^{-47} \textrm{m}^2\left( \frac{kT}{1~\textrm{MeV}}\right)^2 $$

How to prove $\sigma$ proportional to $T^2 $?

Here, $\sigma$ is scattering cross section and $T$ is the temperature.

Comment: Many inflationary models predict a power spectrum that follows a power law.